# C# How to block a thread until all responses from emails sent arrives

Tags: c#, multithreading

Problem description:
I want to create a new thread to send some emails. Implementation:

```
Thread _thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartSendingEmails));
```

The function called:

```
public void StartSendingEmails()
        {
            var engine = new SendGridEmailEngine(From, FromName)
            {
                TemplateUrl = _templateUrl,
                QueryValues = _queryValues,
                MailHeaders = _mailHeaders
            };

            engine.SendEmail(EmailContent, Subject);
        }
```

And the sender function:

```
public void SendEmail(string emailContent, string subject)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            LastResponseReceived = DateTime.Now;

            foreach (var listItem in QueryValues)
            {
               //other operations....

                // 50 emails stack => wait...
                while (counter - ReceivedResponses > 50)
                    Thread.Sleep(100);

                //increase number of sent emails
                counter++;
                SendEmail(_from, _fromName);
            }

        //wait for all responses to be received
        while (ReceivedResponses < QueryValues.Count && (DateTime.Now - LastResponseReceived).TotalMinutes <= 2)
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

        //force exit if more than 2 min left and not all the responses received
        if (ReceivedResponses < QueryValues.Count && (DateTime.Now - LastResponseReceived).TotalMinutes >= 2)
            WriteLog(string.Format("Forced exit!);
}
```

Wich calls:

```
public void SendEmail(string from, string fromName)
        {
            //other operations
            client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(client_SendCompleted);
        }
void client_SendCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            ReceivedResponses++;
            LastResponseReceived = DateTime.Now;

            if (e.Error != null)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                SentEmailsSuccessfully++;
            }
        }
```

And here is the problem. All emails are sent but the thread is not waiting for all responses. Is there a way to keep the tread alive than what i have done using?

```
    //wait for all responses to be received
    while (ReceivedResponses < QueryValues.Count && (DateTime.Now - LastResponseReceived).TotalMinutes <= 2)
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Comment: Threads are an excessively expensive solution to this problem; there are better ways to solve it. Think of making a thread as hiring a worker. Would you hire a worker and pay them to sleep until an email was received?

Answer (score 2):

You should encapsulate each complete send operation into a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) object. You can `await` the result of [`Task.WhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160384.aspx) to wait for all the tasks to complete.

```
List<Task> sendTasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var listItem in QueryValues)
{
  sendTasks.Add(SendEmailAsync(_from, _fromName);
}

// wait for all responses to be received
await Task.WhenAll(sendTasks);
```

To provide a method to cancel the operation if it takes too long, simply use a [`CancellationTokenSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.aspx) with a timeout.

```
using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)))
{
  List<Task> sendTasks = new List<Task>();

  foreach (var listItem in QueryValues)
  {
    sendTasks.Add(SendEmailAsync(_from, _fromName, cts.Token);
  }

  // wait for all responses to be received
  await Task.WhenAll(sendTasks.ToArray()).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```